# Passing twig variables to Vue.js 3 components

Tags: vue.js

I need to implement Vue.js 3 on my existing Twig templates. The problem is that if I mount an app on my main.ts it automatically overwrites all the content in main app div.

**main.ts:**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp(App);

app.mount('#app');
```

**main.html.twig:**

```
<div id="app">
    <p>test</p>
</div>
```

This way p tag gets deleted along with any Vue components I may put there.

Vue.js 2 way was following:

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {},
});
```

This way I loaded every Vue component into the Vue app and it didn't destroyed the content of app div.

What is the way to implement this on Vue.js 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by removing the `<template></template>` part from an `App.vue` component. If template is empty - it uses the template from the element it's being mounted to.